# Funny/Weird Mechanics of the print() Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in the process of learning python. I am currently learning how to define your own functions and I had some difficulty trying to understand the difference between returning a value and printing it. The descriptions that I have read about the subject were not so clear to me, so I started experimenting on my own and I think I got it by now. If I am not wrong, the difference is that you can pass the value of a `return` expression as an argument to another function and you cannot do that with the value of a `print()` function. While experimenting, I encountered some unexpected outputs.

The first thing I did was write the following code in the Python Interpreter:

```
>>>print(print('hello'))
```

The output was:

> hello
>
> None

This made me believe the following: the `print('hello')` function gets executed first and the text `hello` shows up. Then the expression `print(print('hello))` evaluates to `None` since you cannot use a print() function as an argument of another function. So far so good.

The next code I entered was:

```
>>>a = print('hello')
```

You normally do not expect an output when assigning something to a variable, but in this case the output was:

> hello

This is what I think: the `print('hello')` expression gets executed and outputs the text `hello`. Then the `print('hello')` expression gets stored in the variable `a`.

So this led me to the last line of code I entered:

```
>>>print(a)
```

Based on the previous outputs, I expected this code to give the following output:

> hello
>
> None

Because the variable `a` will get replaced with `print('hello')` and then you will get the same expression as the first one, i.e.: `print(print('hello'))`.

But this was not the case. The actual output was just:

> None

Now I have a couple of unanswered questions:

1. Why is the output of the last code just `None`?
2. If you cannot put a print() function inside another print() function, why is the output `None`? Why does it not give you an error message?
3. Are any of my assumptions wrong (including the one about the difference between `return` and `print`)?

I know that I made this post way too long, but I like to give the whole context so possible helpers will know my situation and maybe adjust their way of helping to fit the situation the best.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You nearly got it. `print` returns `None`, so if you do `a = print('hello')` then the right side will be evaluated and "hello" is printed and `a` will be `None` afterwards. If you do a `print(a)` later it will show this `None`.

Comment: the last example the value of `a` is what `print("hello")` returns not the statement itself. and `print` returns `None` so that got assigned to `a`.

Comment: `a = print('hello')` doesn't store "the expression `print('hello')`" in `a`; it stores the *return value* of `print('hello')` in `a`, which is `None`.

Comment: try `print(None)` and notice that it will print the string `"None"`. That's because the string `'None'` is the string representation of the value `None` (which is the equivalent of `null` in .C++).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Then the `print('hello')` expression gets stored in the variable `a`

No, the variable `a` does not hold the expression. Generally you cannot assign an expression to a variable. What actually happens is that you assign the **result** of the expression to the variable. Subtle difference but very important.

Every function in Python returns something. If you write

```
>>> a = fn()
```

then you store in `a` the result of calling `fn`, not the expression `fn()`. If for example

```
def fn():
    return 1
```

then `a` is now `1`. It just happens that `print` function returns `None`.

On the other hand `print` function has a **side effect**. The side effect is that it pushes whatever you pass to it to the standard output (if you don't mess with `sys` then to `sys.stdout`). It "prints".

So lets analyze your example:

```
>>> a = print('hello')
```

What happens is: `print('hello')` is called. The side effect fires: `hello` is send to the screen. Then the result of calling `print` is stored in `a` which is `None`. Doing

```
>>> print(a)
```

simply prints `None` because that's what `a` is now.